# Unable to stop dlv debug --headless again - running in a docker container on mac

Tags: delve

How do you stop delve headless debugger?

Note: I am runningthis from a docker container on mac, and installed like this:

```
go get -u github.com/derekparker/delve/cmd/dlv
```

From [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-go/wiki/Debugging-Go-code-using-VS-Code) it starts ok, but how do you stop it again.

```
dlv debug --headless --listen=:2345
```

`ctrl + c` etc. do not work - any special trick?

Comment: I have same issue. did you find how to stop the process?

Comment: Nope, let me know if you find it ;-) Probably a bug...

Comment: Didn't find either. Just killed the process. `ps aux | grep dvl` find PID and the `kill pid_number`

Comment: I do the same, let hope for the better :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use `kill -SIGINT $PID`

delve will ignore SIGINT in headless mode